# Oracle: how to add a text node into an existing element

Tags: xml, oracle, updatexml

In Oracle, you can write:

```
update t
set xml = updateXML(xml, '/a/b/text()', 'gaga')
```

This works only if you already have some text in the `<b>` element. How to update the document and "add some text" in `<b>` if the document in the database looks like:

```
<a>
    <b/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
update t
set xml = updateXML(xml, '/a/b', XMLType('<b>gaga</b>'))
```

I don't find this very elegant, but I am not sure you can do better.